# Simple user management library for Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, user-management, boilerplate, email-verification

I find myself implementing user management over and over again in almost the same way in each Spring Boot Project:

- `user/login`
- `user/register`
- `user/reset`
- `user/activation` (email verification)

**Is there a user library/plugin for user management in Spring Boot** which can handle all the overhead boilerplate in an opinionated way, so that it just takes some configuration (`passwordEncoder`, smtp credentials, UserDetails, ...)?

I know there are some Oauth clients and identity managements (Okta, Keycloak etc.)  which can be connected quite easily, but I'd like something (cheaper and) more lightweight.

Comment: I found the easiest to use Keycloak (https://www.keycloak.org/), but that is not a library for your project, it is a separate application that you connect to. You can embed it as well it seems (https://www.baeldung.com/keycloak-embedded-in-spring-boot-app) but I have no experience with that.